# Abbreviations for local filtype buffers only

Tags: autocmd, abbreviations

After typing `tds` I would like to see it replaced with the current time stamp in Markdown files, but eg. NOT while editing C source code.

The following mostly works (stripped for brevity) except that the the abbreviation `tds` is available in every buffer (mode) not just a markdown mode buffer.

```
augroup TXT | au!
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.asciidoc,*.md,README,TODO,CHANGELOG,NOTES,ABOUT
\ setlocal autoindent expandtab tabstop=8 softtabstop=2 shiftwidth=2 |
\ :iab <buffer> <expr> tds strftime("%F %b %T")
augroup END
```

How can I define an abbreviation to be available in certain buffer modes only?

Comment: I expect the `|` is the issue—it’s being executed globally, rather than attached to the autocommand. Try separating it, or using the (after/) ftplugin directory, which is better anyway.

Comment: That's been the issue, it works now as expected!

Comment: Great, I've written an answer

Answer (score 3):

When creating an autocommand, the `:au` part interprets `|` as a command separator. Just like for mappings, you need to escape it:

```
au setlocal autoindent expandtab tabstop=8 softtabstop=2 shiftwidth=2 \| inoreabbrev <buffer> <expr> tds strftime("%F %b %T")
```

Or, use two autocommands:

```
au setlocal autoindent expandtab tabstop=8 softtabstop=2 shiftwidth=2
au inoreabbrev <buffer> <expr> tds strftime("%F %b %T")
```

Or, my preferred solution, put it in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/markdown.vim`:

```
setlocal autoindent expandtab tabstop=8 softtabstop=2 shiftwidth=2
inoreabbrev <buffer> <expr> tds strftime("%F %b %T")
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to run the abbreviation command only for that buffer.

```
autocmd FileType markdown iab <buffer> tds strftime("%F %b %T")
```

I've also made it into a `FileType` event autocommand, instead of a `BufRead,BufNewFile`. So it changes this stuff when filetype is set. I think it's more suitable, but in most cases won't make a lot of difference.

I got most of this from https://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/12.html#filetype-events.

Comment: Been on this link before. Doesn't work for me, abbreviation is available in every buffer. Using Neovim fwiw.

Comment: Note this should be `inoreabbrev <buffer>`